# My jQuery Autocomplete suggestions are sometimes positioned wrong

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a slightly strange but slightly predictable problem with jQuery Autocomplete. I'm using this little fella here: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

It works really well, however I have a GUI that moves around a lot as users add and remove products from their shopping basket.

At some points, the Autocomplete text box is down the bottom of the page under a div that shows/hides at different times. When the Autocomplete returns to the top of the page if the user wants to start again, sometimes the suggestions of the Autocomplete are being displayed in their bottom of the screen position!

Please check my screens shots, the first it all working fine, the 2nd with the dodgy positioning. Even just clicking the screen seems to fix it, but I obviously want it positioned correctly before the user sees it!

---

### Good positioning..........

[image: Autocomplete working]

---

### Bad positioning..........

[image: Autocomplete out of position]

Comment: Are you showing/hiding the div by using display:block/none, or the visibility:visible/hidden CSS?